# Kotlin Class causes App to crash

Tags: android, class, kotlin

I tried to incorporate classes into my program, but now I can't get my program to work (no errors, just crashes). I have isolated the part that causes the crash in an extra project. Can someone help me?

```
package com.mietvertrag.simon.test

imports...

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    data class Contract(var adr:CharSequence, var dat:CharSequence, var mitr:CharSequence, var num:CharSequence)

    lateinit var v1: Contract
    lateinit var vertrag1: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        v1.adr = "Treestreet 24"
        vertrag1 = findViewById(R.id.text)

    }

}
```

Comment: Stack trace would be useful to give an answer, but just a thought would be that you are using v1 without instantiating it.

Comment: how you are overriding  onCreate method without even extending Activity class ?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips to learn how to debug your code

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to set a value to a property of a class instance that has not been initialized:

```
v1.adr = "Treestreet 24"
```

So initialize it:

```
v1 = Contract("Treestreet 24", "", "", "")  <br/>
```

As for the *no errors, just crashes*:  
you must use the Logcat to review the errors or you will never succeed in building apps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is v1 not initialize yet.